# How to invoke a command using specific proxy server?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, proxy

Some applications support proxy (http proxy or socks proxy), and some are not.

For browsers, I can specify proxy server in the preferences/options dialog, and other applications may be able to configure proxy servers in config files.

For general purpose, can I invoke a command using a specific proxy? Like following:

```
$ proxy-exec --type sock5 --server 1.2.3.4:8000 -- wget/ftp ...
```

I'm using Ubuntu Maverick.

*P.S.*

In win32, it can be implemented by hijacking the socket dlls, maybe, I'm not familiar with Linux programming, but I guess it's possible in Linux. though.

Answer (score 18):

Most Linux commands that access the Internet look in the `HTTP_PROXY`, `FTP_PROXY`, and `SOCKS_SERVER` environment variables for proxy information.  So, to do something like your example, just run:

```
export SOCKS_SERVER=1.2.3.4:8000
wget http://superuser.com/q/262956
```

The syntax for `HTTP_PROXY` and `FTP_PROXY` is slightly different:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4:3128/
export FTP_PROXY=ftp://1.2.3.4:25/
```

The default GNOME desktop environment included with Ubuntu's proxy settings has an *Apply System-Wide* button, which will automatically set those environment variables for you.  Otherwise, you can add the `export` lines to your `~/.bashrc` file to make them take effect at every login.

Unfortunately, `wget` doesn't support SOCKS at all.  You can use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/), which is included with Ubuntu, to achieve many things that `wget` does.  Unfortunately, it doesn't check `SOCKS_SERVER`, while it does check `HTTP_PROXY` (as does `wget`).  To use curl to download this page with a SOCKS5 server (performing DNS resolution with that server) and save it as `superuser.html`, run this:

```
curl --socks5-hostname 1.2.3.4:8000 http://superuser.com/q/262956 > superuser.html
```

If you want to make `curl` always use that SOCKS proxy, you could create a shell alias.  Just add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias curl='curl --socks5-hostname 1.2.3.4:8000'
```

You will need to restart your terminal or run that line as if it were a command for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I've tried `wget` with `SOCKS_SERVER`, but it seems not work. `wget` only read proxy settings from `/etc/wgetrc`. I tried `links`, too, it's okay to specify `links -socks-proxy 127.0.0.1:7878 <url>`, but it's failed using `export SOCKS_SERVER=...; links <url>`.

Comment: @谢继雷:  Unfortunately some programs don't read `SOCKS_SERVER`, though many popular ones like `ssh` do.  Also, `wget` doesn't seem to support SOCKS at all.  You can, however, use `curl`.  I'll add information to my answer about that.

Comment: Also `youtube-dl` doesn't read `SOCKS_SERVER`, it reads `http_proxy` instead. And it doesn't support socks proxy. Umm... A list of programs and their supported proxy environ vars can be very helpful.

Comment: If you search [BXR.SU](http://BXR.SU/), it doesn't look like anything supports SOCKS_SERVER at all, certainly not [OpenSSH](http://mdoc.su/o/ssh).  It's most certainly only an option supported by the `socksify` utility from the [security/dante](http://ports.su/security/dante) package.

Comment: `wget(1)` can support SOCKS proxy since [version 1.4.0 (circa 1999)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/diff/NEWS?id=31d6616c483359af431f4c33c3c5b237cd8d4426) **if build with `--with-socks`** which is almost never the case in packaged versions.

Answer (score 10):

Try [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/).

It can be installed with `apt-get`. Then you'll need to create a config file in either of

```
1) ./proxychains.conf
2) $(HOME)/.proxychains/proxychains.conf
3) /etc/proxychains.conf **
```

and you'll be able to invoke another commands like `proxychains wget google.com` - the connections will go through proxy. You can specify multiple proxies used at once or in random order.

For example:

```
➜  ssh -ND 4000 sockshost &
[1] 3446
➜  wget whoer.net -q -O- | grep remote_addr
89.71.*.*
➜  cat proxychains.conf 
[ProxyList]
socks5 127.0.0.1 4000
➜  proxychains wget whoer.net -q -O- | grep remote_addr
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:4000-<><>-95.211.121.18:80-<><>-OK
78.98.*.*
```

I stripped some HTML tags and IPs, but as you can see the proxy was used and the IP address did change.

Comment: Since the original [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) is unmaintained, you can use [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) instead.

Answer (score 1):

wget does not support socks, curl works as [Patches](https://superuser.com/a/262972/98591) said:

```
curl --socks5-hostname 1.2.3.4:8000 https://superuser.com/q/262956/66003
```

If you need wget you can install `tsocks`.

Install `sudo aptitude install tsocks` and setup:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/tsocks.conf
server = 1.2.3.4
server_type = 5
server_port = 8000
```

Usage:

```
tsocks wget https://superuser.com/q/262956/66003
```

Comment: torsocks seems to be the updated version of tsocks: http://superuser.com/a/1000811/128124